# Static File Whitenoise Heroku Django issue

Tags: django, heroku

I have an API developed in Django and Django Rest Framework. We need one page in "normal" Django that will be open once a month maybe (so no need for CDN for the static files). Gunicorn + whitenoise is what we went ahead with.

The `collectstatic` works fine in both build phase and after build phase.

The url generated on the page is `href=/static/css/edit_card.a1c6e0f9f12e.css/` but the console shows the 404 not found for that resource and there are no styles applied to the page.

Relevant django settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_media/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR + "/static_folder/"),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

The relevant file in the repo is in `/static_folder/css/edit_card.css`
The relevant file on the heroku instance after running `collectstatic` is in 
`static_media/css/edit_card.a1c6e0f9f12e.css` (together with the normal version and other compressed files)

I can manually access this link `url/static/css/edit_card.css` which is ridiculously weird.

This works fine when `DEBUG = True`. When in `False`/production it does not.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

EDIT:

`Template`

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/edit_card.css" %}/>
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what your problem is? Because when `DEBUG` is `false` (in production), it is supposed to work that way. One of the reasons is that when you deploy a new version of that asset, browsers and CDNs don't use the cached version.

Comment: Have you enabled WhiteNoise by adding it to your MIDDLEWARE list?

Comment: @D.Evans Yes sir I have had.

Comment: @dethos Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question. The problem is that the url generated on the page by `{ static "/css/edit_card.css"` presents the upper mentioned link (`edit_card.112f1rf123.css`) however, the network console shows 404 and there are no styles applied to the page, while the file is present in the `static_media` directory..

Comment: @BorkoKovacev Did you already tried to use `{% load staticfiles %}` instead of `{% load static %}`?

Comment: Because if your django version older than `1.10`, `staticfiles` is required, as explained where: http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#make-sure-staticfiles-is-configured-correctly

Comment: @dethos Our django version is `Django==1.11.4`. I'm unsure what seems to be the problem :(

Comment: Not easy to understand where the issue is. Is the `'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'` the second element of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list? just after `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'`?

Comment: @dethos it is. One solution that has worked for me right now was to completely remove `{% load static %}` and `{% static path %}` from the template. I directly linked it to `/static/css/edit_card.css` and it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be too late for this response, but I'm surprised nobody noticed the error.

Your template is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={% static "css/edit_card.css" %}/>
```

The problem is that the `href` attribute is not quoted and it's taking the last `/` as part of the path. That's why the URL is: `href=/static/css/edit_card.a1c6e0f9f12e.css/` (note the `/` at the end).

The solution would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/edit_card.css" %}" />
```

URL is between quotes and there's a space after the path.